# How to set hits per page on Algolia autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, algolia

In the documentation of autocomplete, [it states](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#hits):

> Hits
>
> To build a source based on Algolia's hits array, just use:
>
> ```
> {
>   source: autocomplete.sources.hits(indexObj, { hitsPerPage: 2 }),  
>   templates: {
>     suggestion: function(suggestion, answer) {
>       // FIXME
>     }   
>   }
> }
> ```

However, I'm not sure what the `idexObj` is supposed to be. I have an instance of instantsearch with three indexes, but passing either index gives the following error:

```
autocomplete.min.js?_=1494237458641:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_ua' of undefined
```

whilst passing `indexObj` results in:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: indexObj is not defined
```

I need to limit the number of results show and I suppose passing the source should do it, but I can't figure out how to pass it.

Comment: You need to generate the index as shown in this example: https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#standalone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rishipuri was right but because I am using multiple indexes, this example didn't really count. However, it did cause me to go back to [the documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/auto-complete/#multi-category-user-interface) where I found the following:

```
autocomplete('#aa-search-input', {}, [
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(players, { hitsPerPage: 3 }),
      displayKey: 'name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Players</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.name.value + '</span><span>'
              + suggestion._highlightResult.team.value + '</span>';
        }
      }
    },
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(teams, { hitsPerPage: 3 }),
      displayKey: 'name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Teams</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.name.value + '</span><span>'
              + suggestion._highlightResult.location.value + '</span>';
        }
      }
    }
]);
```

Note `hitsPerPage` being passed at the source definition here, which is very useful.